# Debugging php script timeout?

Tags: php

Is it possible to get a stack trace logged when a php script times out? I am trying to find out why this vbulletin php script is locking up. I have no idea where to start with finding out why its locking up. I don't even know where to look because vbulletin is so large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to output something like `die(__FILE__.':'.__LINE__);` consequently to find out where exactly it timed out.

Comment: not really possible with vbulletin. It would take weeks putting it in every possibly place.

Comment: You could do it pretty easily with any code :). Here's advanced approach on how to profile your code: http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler . Profiling data could be easily visualized with apps like KCacheGrind... It's very nice! Try to get it working!

Comment: Profiler worked brilliantly. Turns out it was hanging inside of php's mail function.