# Debugging a 404 error for an existing page

Tags: php, timeout, http-status-code-404, integration

I have a PHP script on server which, generally...

1. Receives url-encoded data via POST from Service A
2. Makes adjustments to the data for Service B
3. Submits to Service B

This works great except that every so often, Service A reports that the script 404'd (was not found).

I am trying to figure out two things:

1. Why would a 404 error occur if the script exists and is accessible?
2. I believe the issue is related to a timeout somewhere in the script. Is there a way that I can avoid the 404 error and perhaps log some helpful messages, [like in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797911/debugging-php-script-timeout)?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're currently re-uploading the file it could temporarily return a 404.

Comment: Thanks. In this case the file is rarely touched.

Comment: Can you tell if the 404 is returned by PHP or by the web server?

Comment: I _believe_ the 404 is being returned by the web server. In the backend of Service A, it is reported that the response returned was `HTTP Status Code: 404. cURL Error: 0`

Comment: If it's coming from the server, it should also return a generic 404 page (e.g. here's Apache's: http://articles.slicehost.com/assets/2008/12/5/apache-404-footer.jpg) or whatever file is configured to be used when a 404 happens. In this case, you should also have something in the web server's log file. Try checking that to see if anything interesting shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using some naked code base (i.e. some procedural or poorly architected object oriented solution). With acknowledged PHP frameworks like [Zend](http://www.zend.com) or [Symfony](https://symfony.com), you could define error handlers for such situations and given the sent and received data handle it appropriately like retrying that particular request or, with a [queue system](https://www.google.hu/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20queue%20systems) being employed, reschedule the job.

An advice for you, don't care about the why. Prepare your app for the what-when.

Comment: I think that even if the OP did decide to migrate his entire codebase over to Zend or Symfony, etc., it's still good to know *why* this is happening before doing the migration. And I don't think a queue system would be necessary if things were coded/configured correctly to begin with.

Comment: Of course it's good to know, but I had the impression that the OP has no control over those services and, in addition, the problem appears to be intermittent.